# Reading 1 line when i writing some lines in a binary file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles, filewriter, file-read

When I continue to write in a number of lines to a binary file, I read only the first line and the other lines are empty, python 3.x

```
lines = ['1-1:3|12rq2r-1:1|2-2:1|20hjk-10:1', '1-11:3|21-11:1|22yrety-12:1|23-13:1']
path = os.getcwd()+ '\\myfile.bin'
output = open(path, 'ab')
with open(inputFile,buffering=1000000) as f:
    for line in lines: 
        comprass = zlib.compress(line.encode('utf-8'))
        output.write(comprass)
```

Now I read all of the file

```
path = os.getcwd()+ '\\myfile.bin'
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
      count = 0
      r = f.read()
      txt = zlib.decompress(r).decode('utf-8')
```

In txt i managed to get only line1

```
'1-1:3|12rq2r-1:1|2-2:1|20hjk-10:1'
```

I then try read it line by line:

```
path = os.getcwd()+ '\\myfile.bin'
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
      line = f.readline()
      while line:
          txt = zlib.decompress(r).decode('utf-8')
          print(txt)
          line = f.readline()
```

but in line - `txt = zlib.decompress(r).decode('utf-8')`
I get a running error:

> txt = zlib.decompress(line).decode('utf-8') zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream

I think the problem occurs because i keep writing to file and you can't insert a line drop.

Is there another way to manually add a row to a binary file?
Thanks!

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do here?

Comment: Also, Zlib compressed information may contain a newline character, you can't expect to read write it into a file and be able to correctly read it line-by-line.

Comment: I'm trying to create a compressed lines to file that I can translate later line by line

Comment: Why? What would you do with the data? Is there a reason you can't just compress them as a single stream?

Comment: I create a file that analyzes big data
Every file I read I do operations and finally encode the end result and I have to save it in the file afterwards